# Bulletproof radial glow

Tags: html, css

I need to create an element with radial glow, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UEz88/1/).
But now it's too unstable variant. Are there any better solutions?

Unstable means, that if i'll change text in *span* element, than i should to change *left* property value.

Comment: What do you mean by "unstable"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. please elaborate what you need.

Comment: There's no "radial glow" (unless you mean the background image), and no clear indication of what the problem is. I have no idea what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically justify the text remove the `position`, `left` and `top` definition from `h1 > span` and add the following to the `h1`:

```
h1 {
    ...
    line-height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also see you updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UEz88/2/).